# Passing files under a folder to a JAR file Docker

Tags: docker, jar, dockerfile, config

all.

I am dockerising a JAR file for deployment to Kubernetes.

Currently I am writing the dockerfile, I have my JAR file which takes an argument (file) which it then processes.

Inside my Dockerfile I am creating an image from my JAR and config files without an issue.

What I am slightly stumped with is how to pass the files under the configs/ file as an argument to the JAR.

I.E under configs/ each file should be passed to the JAR file as an argument.

Any ideas?

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY sqlrunner.jar app.jar
COPY configs/ configs/
EXPOSE 8010
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
CMD ["/configs"]
```

Comment: How would you invoke the program without a container system involved?  You say you're trying to run this in Kubernetes; do you have a partial Job spec that demonstrates the issue?  (In a Kubernetes Pod spec, the `args:` will override the Dockerfile `CMD`.)

Comment: `CMD ["/configs/*"]` perhaps?